# How related is this to a 2014 research paper

Tags: papers

In reference to the patent: [US9383895B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9383895B1/en)

The patent sounds quite similar to the following paper.
MixFab: a mixed-reality environment for personal fabrication
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2557090

Comment: Possibly so. However that patent's priority date is in 2012, whereas that paper was published in 2014. So the paper is not prior art.

Comment: @Maca Not a bad answer. Perhaps you should post it as one.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty hard to say how the two documents are related. The patent's filing date predates the cited paper so the paper can not be considered prior art (although it is certainly possible there is other relevant prior art). It is possible the authors of the paper are familiar with the work of the inventors and vice versa. I haven't spent any time reading the two documents so I can't say how similar the techniques described in them are. It is very common to find different research groups working on similar projects.